# How Do I Check If a LIst of Validation Contains At Least One Invalid?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, either

Say I have type like this:

```scala
val checkConstraints : List[Either[NonEmptyList[String], Valid[Data]]
```

How do I check if there is at least one element in this list is a left? i.e. when I did the validation checks it produced a NonEmptyList for at least one element in the List[Data]. Not sure if this is the best way to check if a List[Data] contains at least one element which fails validation. What I did was:

```scala
val result = (check(data.f1), check(data.f2)).mapN{
  case (f1, f2) =>
    Valid(Data(f1, f2))
}.toEither
```

I can think of one way:

```
val dd: List[Data] = result.collect { case Valid(value) => value }

if (data.size =!= dd.size) { // then I know there was at least on failure
  invalid("there is at least one data point which has failed validation")
} else {
  Valid(dd)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may also `sequence` that to get an either of a list instead. Also, an either whose right is a **Valid** doesn't feel right, just have the **Data** directly. Maybe you can show the code that took you to that result? You are probably using the wrong method somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is just go with `exists`, like:

```
val validations: List[Either[String, String]] = List(Left("Err"), Right("Success"))
println(validations.exists(_.isLeft))
```

Will print out `true`:

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZwEEVHwGRHiikLEeh1b3SQ

Answer (score 1):

`Either` is a monad that is doing short-circuiting on the first `Left` value in the list.

So using `sequence` will yield Left if there's at least one `Left` in the list and `Right` otherwise:

```
println(validations.sequence.isLeft)
```